# Why am I getting different predicted probabilities on random forest rf$votes vs. predict()?

Tags: r, random-forest

I ran randomForest on a dataset with binary outcome and want the predicted probabilities (on the same dataset - I don't need separate train/test for this). I was expecting the values for p1 and p2 below to be the same, but clearly they are not. I haven't been able to find a clear description of how they are different. Any help would be appreciated.

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
rf = randomForest(factor(admit)~., data = mydata)
p1 = predict(rf, mydata[,c(2:4)], type = "prob")
p2 <- rf$votes
```

```
> head(p1)
      0     1
1 0.926 0.074
2 0.584 0.416
3 0.166 0.834
4 0.722 0.278
5 0.968 0.032
6 0.258 0.742
> head(p2)
          0          1
1 0.8324324 0.16756757
2 0.7663043 0.23369565
3 0.2447917 0.75520833
4 0.9695431 0.03045685
5 0.9264706 0.07352941
6 0.3351351 0.66486486
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for figuring that out!